# bootstrap issue using R

Tags: r, machine-learning

Does it have any methods to print all selected data when bootstrap is complete?

Once I use the following code

```
library(boot)
set.seed(1234)

rsq = function(data,indices) {
  d = data[indices,]
  fit = lm(formula=mpg~wt+disp,data=d)
  return(summary(fit)$r.square)
}
results = boot(data = mtcars, statistic = rsq, R=1000)
print(results)
plot(results)
boot.ci(results,conf=0.95,type=c('perc','bca'))


BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = results, conf = 0.95, type = c("perc", "bca"))

Intervals : 
Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 0.6838,  0.8833 )   ( 0.6344,  0.8549 )
```

to get confidence interval.I want to print all select obs which selected by bootstrap method.

Thanks.

Comment: @DominicComtois I just updated the code for rsq

Comment: @user3849475 I don't understand what you want. With `R = 1000` you will replicate the bootstrap 1000 times. Do you want to know the row numbers used in each of the 1000 replications?

Comment: @Gregor when rep=1000 completed,I want to see which obs(raw number used) were selected in the boostrap dataset (nearly 63% of total dataset)

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear. You should read more [about the bootstrap[(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) and if you're confused ask on Stats.stackexchange. You don't have a single bootstrap dataset, you have 1000 bootstrap data sets because you set R = 1000. Each one of the 1000 will use a different sample (with replacment) of your original data.

Comment: @Gregor does it have any way to get unique obs from those 1000 bootstrap?

Comment: @user3849475 This is exactly what Dominic's answer show you how to do---unique obs from from each of those 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ind <- list()
rsq <- function(data,indices) {
  d <- data[indices,]
  ind[[length(ind)+1]] <<- indices
  fit <- lm(formula=mpg~wt+disp,data=d)
  return(summary(fit)$r.square)
}
```

Then all your 1000 sets of indices would be in the list `ind`.

Then maybe use unique to see which unique observations were sampled:

```
lapply(ind, unique)[1:2]

[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32

[[2]]
 [1] 29  4  3 15 16  7 32  5 31 17 28 20 26 19 10 18  1  6 24  8
```

Comment: that means those unique obs are all fall into confidence interval for 95%?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that... each bootstrap sample uses a different set of 32 observations, some of which are repeated (except for the first bootstrap which uses all 32 obs). On the long run all will be sample about 1000 times as you could see with `table(unlist(ind))`

Comment: thanks dominic! One more question: if there is id in each line for original data,how to print unique id for those 1000 times?

Comment: You could replace `<<- indices` by something like `<<- data$ID[indices]`or equivalently `<<- data[indices, "ID"]` so in your `ind` list you would have those ID's instead of the row numbers.